# How do I select rows from one table filtered by another table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table *members*:

```
member_id, points
```

And I have another table *bets*:

```
member_id, finished
```

Consider following data for table *members*:

```
1 0
2 15000
3 0
```

And for *bets*:

```
1 -1
1  0
2  1
3  1
3 -1
```

In the table *bets* finished = -1 marks the bet as lost, 0 as unfinished and 1 as won.
How can I select member id's which have 0 points and all their bets are finished? With the data I have given, it should return one row with member id = 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use EXISTS clause:

```
select members.id
from members
where
  points=0
  and not exists (select null from bets where bets.id=members.id and status=0)
```

You can also use a LEFT JOIN:

```
select members.id
from
  members left join bets
  on members.id = bets.id
     and bets.status=0
where
  bets.id is null
  and members.points=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`, like so:

```
select members.member_id, members.points, bets.finished
  from members
  join bets on bets.member_id = members.member_id
  where bets.finished <> 0 and members.points = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join

```
SELECT member_id FROM members m
INNER JOIN bets b
ON m.member_id = b.member_id
WHERE b.finished = 0 AND m.points = 0
```

> An inner join is the most common join operation used in applications and can be regarded as the default join-type. Inner join creates a new result table by combining column values of two tables (A and B) based upon the join-predicate. The query compares each row of A with each row of B to find all pairs of rows which satisfy the join-predicate. When the join-predicate is satisfied, column values for each matched pair of rows of A and B are combined into a result row.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join

In your case, the *join-predicate* is `m.member_id = b.member_id`.

Answer (score 0):

-- Most of the answers don't address your key issue - All of the bets are placed not just one of them
-- Here you go

```
Select memberid 
  from members 
 where points = 0 
   and member id not in (select member id from bets where bet <> -1 )
```

Or For Even Greater Efficiency as data grows to very very high volume

```
Select memberid 
  from members 
 where points = 0 
   and member id not in (select member id from bets where bet <> -1 and bets.memberid = members.memberid)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT m.member_id , b.finished FROM members m
   INNER JOIN bets b
   ON m.member_id = b.member_id
   WHERE m.points = 0
   and b.finished = 1
```

[**LOOK DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/033b0/3)